# Get access to View object during testing

Tags: java, android, barista

I'm using Barista to test my Android app.  At a certain point in my activity's lifecycle, a QR code is displayed on screen.  I'm able to successfully test that the image appears on screen:

```java
BaristaVisibilityAssertions.assertDisplayed(R.id.qrCode);
```

Is there a way to get access to the actual `ImageView` object?  I want to inspect its `Bitmap` and verify that the QR code's contents are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to get access to the activity object as, from there, you can call `findViewById`.  Assuming you have a `BaristaRule<MyActivity>`:

```java
public class MyActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public BaristaRule<MyActivity> baristaRule = BaristaRule.create(MyActivity.class);

    ...
}
```

you can get the activity by `baristaRule.getActivityTestRule().getActivity()`.